# ffmpeg: Extracted wav from mp4 video does not have equal duration as the original video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a mp4 video that is 0.92 seconds, and I am trying to extract the audio of the video to a wav format. I have tried several commands (I have provided a list of some of the commands that I have tried), however, the resulting wav does not have the same duration as the original video (the resulting wav often has a duration of 0.96 seconds instead of 0.92 seconds). Ensuring that the video and audio are synchronous is crucial for what I am doing (the videos are typically videos of a person speaking, and it is important that the speech (audio) is in-sync with the mouth movements of the speaker).

I find it odd that, by extracting audio from a video, the duration changes, even despite what is happening under the hood for the conversion (in terms of codecs used, etc).

Some of the commands that I've tried include:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -c copy -map 0:a -sample_rate 16000 <output>

ffmpeg -i <input> -async  1 -f wav <output>

ffmpeg -i <input> -vn -acodec copy <output>

ffmpeg -i <input> -ac 2 -f wav <output>
```

Any insight would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

**Edit** Output of the command `ffmpeg -ignore_editlist true -i 00026.mp4 output.wav`

```
ffmpeg version 2021-02-28-git-85ab9deb98-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-lib
snappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --en
able-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --e
nable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --
enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwben
c --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --en
able-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 66.100 / 56. 66.100
  libavcodec     58.126.100 / 58.126.100
  libavformat    58. 68.100 / 58. 68.100
  libavdevice    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavfilter     7.107.100 /  7.107.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '00026.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.37.101
  Duration: 00:00:00.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 599 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 160x160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 556 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 65 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, wav, to 'output.wav':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    ISFT            : Lavf58.68.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc58.126.100 pcm_s16le
size=      32kB time=00:00:00.96 bitrate= 273.7kbits/s speed= 212x
video:0kB audio:32kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.238037%
```

Comment: Copy and paste all of the text output from the command `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.wav`.

Comment: I've added the output to the original post. I suspect that this output is also incorrect for the video information. When I query the number of video frames (using ffmpeg or openCV), I get 23, but considering the video has an fps of 25, this is not possible using the 0.98s video duration above (25*0.98 = 24.5 -> 24 frames). When I query using ffprobe, I get a video duration of 0.92, which makes sense to me since 0.92*25 = 23. I also find it odd that ffmpeg and ffprobe output different results in terms of the duration as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to because the video is from a proprietary (private) dataset. Let me look for publicly available video that exhibits the behaviour and get back to you if that's okay.

Comment: I tried about 8 publicly available videos, unfortunately, I am unable to reproduce the problem. Just to elaborate little more, when I call `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.wav`, the duration of the video is 0.98 seconds. When I query the duration of output.wav using `ffmpeg -i output.wav 2>&1`, the duration of the audio is 0.96 seconds. When I query using ffprobe (more specifically, `ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 00026.mp4`), I get that the video and audio is 0.92 seconds which I think is correct as this then gives me the correct frame count.

Comment: This issue persists with other videos in the dataset as well.

Comment: I've added the output to the original post, the video length is still 0.98s and video is still 0.96s (odd that they are different in the first place plus, both are incorrect to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: Without a test file all I can suggest now is to try a new ffmpeg since yours is 5 months old. Get latest *git essentials* from gyan.dev.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out. Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: If I upload one of the files to OneDrive and left it just for 10 minutes and can you download it on your side, would that be okay?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/v/s!AgmiNoclu0DCaoBeO81Duyf6Ohk Thanks! I will leave the link open for today. In the meantime, I will also continue to experiment to see what is causing the issue.

Comment: Durations of the decoded streams are the same: `ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 -map 0:a -f null - && ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 output.wav && ffmpeg -i output.wav -f null -`

Comment: I've updated ffmpeg and when running the first command, it states that the video is 0.98 s long and the audio is 0.96s long. The outputs of the other 2 commands show that the output (audio) is 0.96s as well (hence, the duration is not the same for me). I'm also not sure whether its correct to predict that the audio is 0.96s long because the video has an fps of 25, thus 0.96x25 = 24, but when queried in openCV and using ffprobe (`ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_frames -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -of csv=p=0 test_video.mp4`), it shows that there should be 23 frames.

Comment: When I query using ffprobe (`ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 test_video.mp4`), it shows that the video and audio stream is 0.92 seconds long, which makes more sense to me because, 0.92x25 = 23, which coincides with openCV and ffprobe. Consequently, its also safe to say that there is a discrepancy between ffprobe and ffmpeg

Comment: Hi! I thought I would give you an update from my side... I am still getting different answers (when querying the duration of a given video) when using ffmpeg, ffprobe and opencv. To elaborate, when I try `ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 test.mp4`, it shows that the video and audio are the same (0.92 seconds). When I try `ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -f null -`, it states that there are 23 frames, but if I use the duration provided (0.96s), I am supposed to get 0.96x25 = 24 frames. Furthermore, OpenCV states that the video should have 23 frames.